# As of 2012, what is the best way to implement a custom navigation bar style on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, navigationbar

I know of two methods and each have their own disadvantages:

- http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/
  This one gives you the most flexibility, you can customize everything on the nav bar. However,  you need to use the interface builder to create your nav bar. If you create your nav bar programmatically, it's not possible to have a custom nav bar. Please correct me if I'm wrong, i would love to know the solution.
- http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/
  This one is done all programmatically, however, you are forced to display the nav bar title, and you can't customize the buttons.

Do you guys know of any better method? (Again, it's for iOS 4.0 as I need the app to be compatible with iOS 4.0+)

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 3):

You probably need two methods, conditioned by the OS version.  This is because on 5.0 and later, the drawRect function isn't called.  Instead, 5.0 has it's own routines for custom navigation bar.  I ended up using both 4.0 and 5.0 methods, and determining the version and choosing the proper one at run time.

As far as the first method, I don't see why you really need interface builder.  Just instantiate your objects programmatically and add them as subviews.  Interface builder itself doesn't do much more than that -- it's just a handier way of dealing with them.

Comment: The reason IB is used is because `navigationBar` on `UINavigationController` is read-only. But, by subclassing and changing the class of the navigation bar in IB, you can coerce the navigation controller into populating it's `navigationBar` property with an instance of your subclass that implements `-drawRect:`.

Comment: Owen, can you share you method?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to swizzle methods, add categories or use Interface Builder, instead, you can subclass `UINavigationBar` and use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to change the class of `UINavigationController.navigationBar` to your custom subclass.

```
+ (UINavigationController*)customizableNavigationControllerWithController:(UIViewController*)controller {

NSAssert(controller != nil, @"UINavigationController(CustomNavigationBar) customizableControllerWithController: controller can not be nil");

UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nil] autorelease];

NSData *navControllerData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:navController];

NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:navControllerData] autorelease];

[unarchiver setClass:[CustomNavigationBar class] forClassName:@"UINavigationBar"];

UINavigationController *customizableNavController = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"root"];

customizableNavController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];

return customizableNavController;
```

}